# Laravel get path relative to public instead of root?

Tags: php, path, laravel-4

I want to store all my image paths in a `$images` variable but relative to the `public` directory rather than app root.

```
$images = glob('public/images/*.png'); //this works fine
//however the src would be "localhost:8000/public/images/flower.png"
//instead of "localhost:8000/images/flower.png"
foreach $images as $image
  <img src="$image">
```

I've used `public_path()` but this is obviously wrong as it will get the full path. The obvious solution would be to trim `public` off each image src string, but I find this too hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I can't see another way around it other than doing the trim as glob does not support using capture groups or anything like that.

Comment: Ah, okay I guess I'll stick with what I got. Is `glob` the only way to do this?